# What does :[] do when passed to .send in this Ruby statement?

Tags: ruby

I'm debugging some Ruby code and come across something which I'm not familiar with.

```
  user_array = user_array.send(:[], hash_key)
```

What does this line do? I'm confused by the `:[]` which is passed to `send` as the first argument.

For reference, `user_array` is an instance of a Class (`Chef::Node`), and `hash_key` is a string.

Comment: That is cookie monster...

Comment: Do you know what `send` does?

Comment: `send` calls a method. So at the accepted answer explains, `obj.send(:to_s)` is the same as `obj.to_s`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-send) dynamically calls a method:

```
obj.send(:method, arg1, arg2)
```

will effectively be like:

```
obj.method(arg1, arg2)
```

So in your case the code is equivalent to:

```
user_array.[](hash_key)
```

The method [`[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) is a special method name, which is normally written in ruby using its syntactic sugar form:

```
user_array[hash_key]
```

Answer (score 2):

It simply calls the `[]` method. It returns an element of the array/hash. It's equivalent to call:

```
user_array[hash_key]
```

Answer (score 0):

send calls the first argument with the rest of the parameters.

In this case, it should translate to user_array[hash_key]

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-send